# How to append each read line to string array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a file opened and I know how many lines it has. I need to store each line somehow.

```
FILE * fp = fopen("something.txt", "r");
char allLines[numberOfLines][50];
char line[50];

int i;
for (i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    fgets(line, 50, fp);
    allLines[i][50] = line;
    printf(line);
}
```

How should the assignment and print statements look like?

Comment: Assign: `strcpy(allLines[i], line)`.  Print: `fputs(line, stdout)`.  (There are better ways, but these are the bare minimum.)

Comment: "I know how many lines it has" is a disaster waiting to happen. Please never assume that input data will be what you think it should be, for your own sanity, if not for getting into the habit of writing robust code.

Comment: From Steve's comment you cannot copy a string in C with `=`.

Comment: `printf(line);` is a disaster waiting to happen.  What happens if the inputcontains `25% never responded`?  The answer is "nothing good".  Control the format string; use `printf("%s", line);`.  Why bother with the `line` though?  Why not simply `if (fgets(allLines[i], sizeof(allLines[i]), fp) != NULL)` — which simply copies the data into the right place, but also tests properly for unexpected problems (like an early EOF).

Comment: Duplicate to this foir example this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1842393/694576?